# .NET TelegramBotClient: подключение DI

Tags: .net, telegram-bot, dependency-injection

Пишу бота, нашел несколько способов обработки апдейтов: статические методы / класс-обработчик, реализующий интерфейс IUpdateHandler. А как я могу сюда прикрутить DI? (Мне нужны зависимости в обработчике апдейтов).
Есть, конечно, вариант использовать какое-то статическое публичное поле IServiceProvider и создавать сервисы в обработчике через него, но, кажется, не для этого DI был придуман.

Использую реализацию DI от майкрософтов

Comment: У Майков почти весь код современных фреймворков наглухо приколочен к ServiceProvider, который является антипаттерном Service Locator. Чем вы хуже? Смело используйте тот же подход. / А вообще, ваш бот должен принимать IUpdateHandler, реализация которого передаётся с помощью DI. / Покажите немного кода, чтобы можно было что-то конкретное посоветовать.

Comment: Кажется, вы открыли мне глаза. Я не заметил, что бот действительно может принимать сразу экземпляр класса, реализующего IUpdateHandler. В таком случае, я могу без лишних лишних проблем добавить этот класс в DI и получать его оттуда